# A question regarding continuous differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $\operatorname{f}$ be a real-valued function of one variable that is continuously differentiable on the intervall $(a,b)$, except possibly at $\gamma\in(a,b)$. Let $\operatorname{f}$ be such that $\operatorname{f}(x)\to 0$ when $x\to \gamma$. Let
$$\operatorname{F}(x) = \cases{\operatorname{f}(x),\enspace \forall x\in (a,b):x\neq \gamma \\ 0, \enspace x = \gamma}$$
Is $\operatorname{F}$ necessarily continuously differentiable on $(a,b)$? If so, how should I go about proving it? Can the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem somehow be used to prove it (or disprove it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No $F$ is not necessarily continuously differentiable. Consider for instance the absolute value function $F(x) = |x|$. Here $\gamma = 0$ and the interval can be any positive interval including $0$.

Clearly, $f(x)$ is differentiable at any non-zero point ($f'(x) = \pm 1$), but at $0$ there is no derivative even though $F(0) = 0$.

Comment: What proprties would I have to Impose on $\operatorname{F}$ in order for it to be continuously differentiable on $(a,b)$? In addition to the aforementioned ones that is.

Comment: The derivative should exist and be continuous.

Comment: @juanarroyo You're just repeating the definition.

Comment: @zhw. lol I know the point is you're probably not going to find many good conditions that don't exclude a lot of $C^1$ functions.